# ClassNotFoundException: io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver in python file using command line but not in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, databricks

I am creating a python wheel to use with Databricks. The script connects to a database using Trino. In the IDE(PyCharm), i can connect and the script runs fine. When I create my wheel, I get an error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.load.
> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver

my project is set up like this:

```
/path/to/example/project/
    ├── src/                    
    │   └── my_test_code/          
    |       ├── __init__.py
    |       ├── __main__.py 
    |       ├── trino-jdbc-405.jar.jar    
    |       ├── config.ini           
    │       └── module.py      
    ├── pyproject.toml              
    └── README.md
```

my pyproject.toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name= "my_test_code"
version = "0.0.1"

[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
"" = "src/"


[project.scripts]
run='my_test_code.__main__:main'
```

The SparkSession is set up in the module and I add the trinodriver.jar using

```
def __init__(self):
    jars = ["trino-jdbc-405.jar", "ojdbc9-23.2.0.0.jar"]
    print(jars)
    self.spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("P10")
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", ":".join(jars))
        .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1") \
        .getOrCreate())
    self.config = ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
    self.config.read("config.ini")
```

Then I load the dataframe:

```
  def get_dataframe_from_SQL(self, sql, connection):
        df = (self.spark.read.format("jdbc")
              .option("url", connection["host"])
              .option("driver", connection["driver"])
              .option("query", sql)
              .option("user", connection["username"])
              .option("password", connection["password"])
              .load())
        return df
```

When I run the script from the IDE, my dataframe loads perfectly. Once I run it using the wheel from the command line, I get the error.

I imagine its a path issue that PyCharm is correcting for me. I tried a similar script that doesn't need the .jar files to load and worked.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "dev/python/databricks_wheel_test/bin/run", line 8,
> in 
> sys.exit(main())
> ^^^^^^   File "/dev/Python/databricks_wheel_test/src/my_test_code/**main**.py",
> line 62, in main
> df = p10.get_dataframe_from_SQL(sql, connection)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/dev/Python/databricks_wheel_test/src/my_test_code/P10.py",
> line 56, in get_dataframe_from_SQL
> .load())
> ^^^^^^   File "/Python/databricks_wheel_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
> line 307, in load
> return self._df(self._jreader.load())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/dev/Python/databricks_wheel_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1322, in **call**
> return_value = get_return_value(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/dev/Python/databricks_wheel_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py",
> line 169, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/dev/Python/databricks_wheel_test/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 326, in get_return_value
> raise Py4JJavaError( py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.$anonfun$driverClass$1$adapted(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.(JDBCOptions.scala:41)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:346)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with creating the wheel file. Can you please provide more details from the error message? If you scroll down on the error message and look for, I think, "Caused By" or something like that, you'll get more details about what's causing the issue.

Comment: I updated the post with the error trace

Comment: Have you confirmed that the username that you're using has the right level of access to the table that you're trying to read? Also, are you sure that networking settings on the sql server is not blocking databricks clusters' IPs?

Comment: Yes, the username can access the table. It works fine in the IDE. My databricks cluster can access the database from notebooks just fine. But I haven't uploaded the .whl since it fails from the command line. I have looked in the .whl and the .JAR and .INI files aren't listed. I am exploring using a python-library to include the files.